# Background image in the webpage

Tags: html, css, grails, background-image

I am new on Groovy and Grails and currently making a personal website. I want to put an image(which is in asset folder) as a background in index.gsp. How can I do that?

Comment: It's not Grails question. Check HTML and CSS. e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_body_background

Answer (score 1):

You can use asset tag .

```
<asset:image src="image dir .."  />
```

For background image it will be better to css

```
body {
 background: url(../images/backgraound.png) repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<head>
<style>
body{
background-image:url('./assets/bg.jpg');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
```

Or

```
<body style="background-image:url('./assets/bg.jpg');">
....
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your images are in  grails-app/assets/images folder
2. In the page you wish to include image .. add
   `<asset:image src="filename.png"/>`